# How to fetch data from two table in one go

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement where I have to fetch data from database table.
Condition is,

There are two tables with identical columns like `name`, `mobile`, `address`, `age`.
 Ex. table names like **Student** and **Teacher**.

now if I don't find anything in **student** table then I will retrieve data from **Teacher** table.

how to write this query ?

Comment: Do you just mean you want to `union [all]` the queries from both tables, since their structures are the same? Or does it have to actually be conditional, so you only query `teacher` if `student` is empty - or are you using the same key to search both tables?

Comment: No. Not exactly. If I don't find anything in first table then I will retrieve data from second table. I will never go to second table if I have data in first table.

Answer (score 2):

To get results from the two tables you would use UNION ALL. Here however you only want to access table Teacher when there are no matching rows in table Student. This is slightly more difficult. You can still use UNION ALL, but need an EXISTS clause on your teacher query.

```
select * from student
union all
select * from teacher where not exists (select * from student);
```

Comment: No. I am not asking if there exists a student that has something in common with the teacher. I am asking if there exists a student at all. In the actual query there may be where clauses involved which would have to be added here, but there will be no where clause to match students with teachers.

Comment: Ok fine, I get that!! Strange requirement.